# Implementing structures inside multiple classes, which implement a common interface, with different data types

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have an interface `M` which is implemented by classes `A` and `B`.
Both classes expose a single structure `S` but the implementation of the structure differs on the data type used in its member(s).

Is this even possible?

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
interface M {
}

class A inherits M {
    struct S {
        int16 value;
    }
}

class B inherits M {
    struct S {
        int32 value;
    }
}
```

I could now declare two variables of type `M` and instantiate them using `A` or `B`:

```
M x = new A();
M y = new B();
```

Both `x` and `y` would expose the same structure `S` but `x.S.value` would represent an int16 value and `y.S.value` would represent an int32 value.

The purpose of this approach would be to define a series of structures that can store the exact same information and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to populate them.

The problem is that such information can be represented using different `int` sizes (1 byte, 2 bytes, 4 bytes, etc...).

**EDIT #1**

Ok, so let me explain, exactly, what I'm doing (or trying to do).

I have implemented a file system parser which supports both FAT12 and FAT16. To extend it, so it supports other *compatible* file formats, I'd just need to be able to keep the same code but, some how, be able to change structures fields data types; for example, FAT_BIGDOS file systems have the exact same structure as a FAT16 file system but use 32 bit sectors.

Does this clarify my question?

**Edit #2**

Consider this structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct ParameterBlock {
    public UInt16 BytesPerSector;
    public byte SectorsPerCluster;
    public UInt16 ReservedSectors;
    public byte NumberOfFATCopies;
    public UInt16 RootEntries;
    public UInt16 TotalSectors;
    public byte MediaDescriptor;
    public UInt16 SectorsPerFAT;
    public UInt16 SectorsPerTrack;
    public UInt16 HeadsPerCylinder;
    public UInt32 HiddenSectors;
    public UInt32 TotalSectorsBig;
}
```

This structure represents the parameter block of the boot sector of a FATx file system.

In both FAT_BIGDOS and FAT32, the `RootEntries` field is 4 bytes long, instead of 2 (for both FAT12 and FAT16).

Would it be possible to define both cases and encapsulate them inside the same class... and be able decide which one to use at the time the class is instantiated?

Comment: I neither understand what you're trying to do nor what doesn't work. But a nested struct isn't very common and has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: I suspect you are coming from a C or C++ background?   In C# it would probably be better to use a `MemoryStream` on the `byte[]` and parse it manually into a rich class.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? Maybe this is an XY problem and ther might be a different solution.

Comment: _"Both x and y would expose the same structure S but `x.S.value` would represent an int16 value and `y.S.value` would represent an int32 value"_
No, that simply wouldn't compile because you can't access a nested type via an instance.

Comment: "Both x and y would expose the same structure S", no, they won't. That's two *distinct* structures that just happens to have the same short name. Their full qualified name is different, so they're two distinct types, not the same structure. They both expose *a* structure, S, though.

Comment: And you say "The problem is that such information can be represented using different ...", and I don't understand what is the problem with that. You're saying that this *is* a problem, you're not telling us *how* or *why* this is a problem, which can lead us to a way to help you.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen and that's the problem; I cannot generalize the structure thus I cannot expose the same structure with different data types.

Comment: I still don't know what the actual problem is though. So you have multiple structures with different layout. So? What is the problem with that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your mentioned sample is not possible, an interface cannot contain nested types.

If you purpose is to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr, Type)`, you might want to simply expose a `Type` of the struct in your interface, and let the structs implement a common interface.

You could also use a single struct and explicitly specify the locations of the values

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct S
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    int Value32;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    short Value16;
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but the problem is that I'd also need to specify the size of the field, not just the offset.

Comment: By accident I called both fields Value32, I edited it now. The fields must have different names. You specify the size by the type of the field. A short is a 16 bit value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last example, I think this should work and maximizes reuse:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct _ParameterBlock_Pre
{
    public UInt16 BytesPerSector;
    public byte SectorsPerCluster;
    public UInt16 ReservedSectors;
    public byte NumberOfFATCopies;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct ParameterBlock16
{
    public _ParameterBlock_Pre Pre;
    public UInt16 RootEntries;
    public _ParameterBlock_Post Post;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct ParameterBlock32
{
    public _ParameterBlock_Pre Pre;
    public UInt32 RootEntries;
    public _ParameterBlock_Post Post;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct _ParameterBlock_Post
{
    public UInt16 TotalSectors;
    public byte MediaDescriptor;
    public UInt16 SectorsPerFAT;
    public UInt16 SectorsPerTrack;
    public UInt16 HeadsPerCylinder;
    public UInt32 HiddenSectors;
    public UInt32 TotalSectorsBig;
}
```

Of course, it's slightly inconvenient to have to add the `.Pre` and `.Post` when accessing most of the fields, and I hope you can pick better names.

(You're free, of course, at this point to define an `IParameterBlock` interface that both `ParameterBlock16` and `ParameterBlock32` implement. That can always expose a `UInt32` value for `RootEntries`, can hid the `.Pre` and `.Post` ugliness and should probably expose a property that tells you whether it's really a 16 or 32. I wouldn't use a generic here because that just adds its own brand of ugliness)

Comment: It's not ideal but I think I could make it work; I'll post back and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally solve the problem, although not they way I originally intended.

What I ended up doing was to create a separate class for each file system, where FAT12 was the "master" one, and all others simply derived from it and implemented their own versions of the structures, shadowing the original ones.

The only drawback is that all the code that uses these classes had to be updated so that the variables are declared as objects and their members are then referenced at runtime (late binding).

Not ideal; not what I originally wanted, but it works.

[Link to the classes declarations](https://github.com/morphx666/x8086NetEmu/blob/master/x8086NetEmu/Adapters/Disk/FileSystem/FileSystemStructs.vb)

[Link to the actual implementation](https://github.com/morphx666/x8086NetEmu/blob/master/x8086NetEmu/Adapters/Disk/FileSystem/StandardDiskFormat.vb)